# How to post more than 1000 tweets per day on Twitter?

Tags: twitter

For the social network linked to my iPhone app, I would like to avoid to be limited to 1000 tweets per day (limit defined by Twitter). Is there a way to avoid this limit of 1000 tweets per day ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: dare I ask why you would need/want to post >1 kilotweet per day? That's more than one every minute and a half!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's a Twitter limit, I don't think there's really anything you can do about it. I know they have a whitelisting program for applications, but that only seems to apply to GET methods, not updating.